# Обработка ajax данных в PHP с помощью foreach

Tags: php, ajax, массивы, post

Здравствуйте. Возникла небольшая проблема с принятием POST данных при передаче их в PHP скрипт через ajax метод.

Суть в том, что хочется осуществить прием всех данных из json таблицы данных, которые передаются через скрипт. Переменных много, так что вбивать каждую в php файле не вариант вот таким образом:

```
$variable = $_POST["variable"];
```

Конструкция выше работает и скрипт всё делает исправно. Решил использовать цикл foreach для обработки массива данных $_POST, но он почему-то не принимает данные:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $key = $val;
}
```

Не могли бы подсказать, как лучше осуществить задачу и почему foreach в данном случае не принимает данные?

Comment: эээ.. что вы ожидаете от `$key = $val`? удалите это. В терминах вашего вышеприведенного `$_POST['varibale']` при итерациях с `foraech` `$key` будет принимать значение строки-ключа `'variable'`, а `$val` будет становится равным `$_POST['variable']`.

Comment: для наглядности замените это ваше `$key=$val` на `print_r([$key, $val])`

Comment: Спасибо, немного затупил в этом моменте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо terran'у за помощь. При следующей конструкции всё заработало.

```
foreeach($_POST as $key => $val) {
}

extract($_POST);
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, просто ответ был дан в комментарии к вопросу.